# Compute returns using lagged values on date when there are more than one row for the same date in R

Tags: r, datetime, lag

I have a dataset containing data for 6k asset and their marketprices.

I want to compute the daily returns, hence to apply the formula
`martketprice[i] - marketprice[i-1]/marketprice[i-1]` 
The problem is that I have multiple observation for the same datetime, for example for `asset x`, I have 3 observation for the `day t` because it was traded by `investor 1, 2 and 3`. And so on so forth for every asset in the dataset.
So my dataset can look like:

```
investor    asset    datetime      marketprice
1            x          t              10
2            x          t              10
3            x          t              10
```

My idea was to use something like

```
res <- res %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  group_by(asset) %>% 
  mutate(ret = (marketprice - dplyr::lag(marketprice))/dplyr::lag(marketprice, default = NA)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

but it doesn't work since, in the example above, for row 2 would mean use marketprice `[i-1]` which is the same day marketprice, while I want the previous day `[t-1]` to be used (not included in the example dataset)

Furthermore R should check that the `[i-1]` marketprice is not belonging to a date which is more than 4 days distant, hence if the date of row i is `10th of july`, then the computation should apply only if the date `[i-1]` is `6th of july` or closer.

Any idea?

Comment: Will it ever be the case that the same asset is traded at the same date-time at different values?

Comment: no it shouldn't. everyday there should be the same price on the same asset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following assumptions I understand:

1. When repeated day for the same asset, the marketprice is the same, not matter the investor.
2. You don't mind which investor was (so we can remove rows)
3. When day (t) is 5 days or ahead from previous (t-1), a NaN output is ok.

Libraries and some data example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# Data example

set.seed(132) # reproducibility

example = data.frame(
  investor = c(rep(1,3),2,3,rep(2,2),1,
               rep(2,4),rep(3,4)),
  asset = c(rep('A',8),
            rep('B',8)),
  datetime = c(today()+c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6),
               today()+c(1,seq(6,9),seq(16,18))),
  marketprice = c(10,20,30,30,30,sample(c(10,20,30),11,replace = TRUE))
)
```

Example dataset has 2 assets. First one (A) shows how the code deals with several rows for the same day. Second (B) shows how the code deals when there is a jump in dates greater than 4 days.

```
> example
   investor asset   datetime marketprice
1         1     A 2022-05-26          10
2         1     A 2022-05-27          20
3         1     A 2022-05-28          30
4         2     A 2022-05-28          30
5         3     A 2022-05-28          30
6         2     A 2022-05-29          30
7         2     A 2022-05-30          30
8         1     A 2022-05-31          30
9         2     B 2022-05-26          20
10        2     B 2022-05-31          10
11        2     B 2022-06-01          20
12        2     B 2022-06-02          10
13        3     B 2022-06-03          10
14        3     B 2022-06-10          30
15        3     B 2022-06-11          20
16        3     B 2022-06-12          10
```

Dplyr code:

```
# The formula is [price(t)-price(t-1)]/price(t-1) -> dif(price)/lag(price)
ret = example %>% 
  group_by(asset,datetime) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%  # remove repeated dates
  group_by(asset) %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  mutate(ret = ifelse(datetime-lag(datetime) > 4,
                NA,
                (marketprice-lag(marketprice))/lag(marketprice))
         ) %>% # ifelse check the differences of days
  arrange(asset,datetime) # show by assets and dates
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 5
# Groups:   asset [2]
   investor asset datetime   marketprice    ret
      <dbl> <chr> <date>           <dbl>  <dbl>
 1        1 A     2022-05-26          10 NA    
 2        1 A     2022-05-27          20  1    
 3        1 A     2022-05-28          30  0.5  
 4        2 A     2022-05-29          30  0    
 5        2 A     2022-05-30          30  0    
 6        1 A     2022-05-31          30  0    
 7        2 B     2022-05-26          20 NA    
 8        2 B     2022-05-31          10 NA    
 9        2 B     2022-06-01          20  1    
10        2 B     2022-06-02          10 -0.5  
11        3 B     2022-06-03          10  0    
12        3 B     2022-06-10          30 NA    
13        3 B     2022-06-11          20 -0.333
14        3 B     2022-06-12          10 -0.5
```

2 rows dropped because a day had 3 entries of data.

Comment: that should fit perfectly to my needs. A question, suppose i group also by investor at the beginning, the only difference would be that the process considers "holes" in data greater than 4 days individually for each investor right? but the computation should remain the same. I ask this cause i could use it to compute the returns of the asset only when the investor has them, hence in his rows

Comment: If you group by investor, then you are only comparing prices for the same investor . ie in  the output of my example the row 6 would be NA because the previous investor 1 is 5 days below. So, yes, you will have these "holes".  If you want to only compare for the same investor you can do it, but be careful with the `slice(1)`.  You should group before by investors too `group_by(investor,asset,datetime) %>% 
  slice(1)` and then the slice will only remove if there are repeated values for the same investor the same day.

Comment: If this answer was the one you were looking for, consider accepting it (green tick in the upper left corner) ;)